# If I choose Ubuntu develop php app, which edition should I get, Ubuntu Server Edition or Ubuntu Desktop Edition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

If I choose Ubuntu develop php app, which edition should I get, Ubuntu Server Edition or Ubuntu Desktop Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.  The desktop edition is for a work-station.  The server has no GUI.

You should *develop* on the Desktop edition - you'll want a GUI code-editor, debugger, web browser to test with, etc.  You can install a full LAMP stack on Ubuntu very easily to run a localhost webserver.

If you want somewhere to host the server, you can run the server edition, and connect to it remotely (via ssh, ftp etc.) from your development work-station (be it Windows or Ubuntu desktop edition, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one.  The server edition by default is caters more towards running on a server, but you can install PHP and the extensions/libraries on either one.  I think you should really consider which one depending on whether this is going to also be your desktop or not.  If it is, then I would choose the desktop version and just install PHP, Apache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Ubuntu Desktop for PHP development. Ubuntu Server is where you put out your finished PHP work, not for when you are developing coz it has no GUI by default.